# How do I start with this problem? (Dielectric rod with surface charge)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, dielectric

I'm currently preparing for my Physics II exam about electromagnetism so I'm trying to go thorugh some problems.

I came across one that I'm just not able to solve and I thought that maybe someone could lead me in the right direction to solve it.

**The problem is:**

> An infinite long dielectric rod (dielectric constant $\epsilon$) with radius $R$ carries a surface charge $\sigma$. Calculate the electric field and the potential on the inside and outside of the rod.

My first thought is, that a static surface charge in this problem can only arise from a polarization $\vec{P}$. So maybe I need to figure out how write $$div \vec{P} = \rho_b$$
in terms of the surface charge $\sigma$ and then calculate $\vec{E}$ with $\vec{P}$.

I don't really know how to do that though or if it is even the right approach to it. Sadly there are no solutions avaiable so I also wouldn't know if my result would be correct or not.

It would be really great if someone could help me out with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only give you a hint since this is a homework question.
Assuming that the surface charge density is uniform, use Gauss's law for $\mathbf{D}$ and exploit the cylindrical symmetry in the system.